# Return a view with ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing an ASP.NET Core API and I was wondering how I could return a View in a Controller. The goal is to provide a documentation on this page.
What I have tried is to create a Controller class, that returns a ViewResult, like below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then, I have Created a simple view named Index.cshtml in a View/Home repository.
When I launch the app with /api/home, it does return an Internal Server Error (as logged in the JS console of the browser). Although, if I return a random ObjectResult like so:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new ObjectResult(new {bonjour = 1});
    }
```

It does return the correct data model.

Does anyone have an idea on how return a View using ASP.NET Core API Tools ?

Comment: Don't use [tag:asp.net] and [tag:asp.net-mvc] on questions about ASP.NET Core. They are for the old ASP.NET framework

Answer (score 19):

You need to specify full path to your view, because your action name is `Get` not `Index`

Try this

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: @ChristopherJ. You welcome, please mark as solution.

Comment: do yo need to install some nuget library for it to recognize the View class?

Comment: View is a method from Controller. You do not need more than the ASP.NET Core packages already embedded in the project template :)

Answer (score 2):

I think if you define a route on the class you also need to do this for any of the ActionResults so try adding the below:

```
[HttpGet("nameOfThisRoute")]
[Route("nameOfRoute/Get")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return View();
}
```

so your Url will be "api/nameOfRoute/Get"

More Info: http://www.ryadel.com/en/custom-routing-method-names-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/