# How to bind a formated chtml view to an ASP.Net Core 2.0 API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

Failed to find ressources that show the new way to bind a simple HttpGet with IEnumerable type to an automatically generated formated chtml view.

Here is the HttpGet from my ASP.Net Core 2.0 Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Todo> GetTodo()
{
    return _context.Todo;
}
```

And here is the first line of the generated View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Todo>
```

The closest way I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958467/return-a-view-with-asp-net-core-api) to bind the view to the controller would modify the HttpGet method as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return View("~/Views/Todo/TodoList.cshtml");
}
```

With this last snippet I fall in the following error:

> AspNetCore._Views_Todo_TodoList_cshtml+d__11.MoveNext()
>   in TodoList.cshtml

Which means that I have to change the @foreach looping to [make it supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor) by the new razor syntax.

Avoiding the old async/await way, does someone have an idea on how to make this binding successful  ?

Comment: `return View(_context.Todo);`

Comment: What are you trying to do ? passing the list of items to your view ? You can pass that as the second parameter of View method.  `return View("~/Views/Todo/TodoList.cshtml",_context.Todo)` assuming `TodoList` view is strongly typed to the same type as of  what `_context.ToDo` returns

Comment: @Shyju, I am trying to pass the list of items to my view, do you mean I can keep it with IEnumerable if I use the second parameter  ?

Comment: yes. Why don't you try it ?

Comment: I tried it, I have to code it this way:         public IEnumerable<Todo> GetTodo() => View("~/Views/Todo/TodoList.cshtml", _context.Todo) but this will affect the remaining methods of the controller.

Comment: your code is returning a view result. So change the return type of your method to `IActionResult`

Comment: Your first proposal looks going in the right way: I meant public IEnumerable<Todo> GetTodo() => View("~/Views/Todo/TodoList.cshtml", _context.Todo) but I need to find the solution for the other methods su as         [HttpGet("{id}")], PUT,POST, and DELETE.